# Insert every jpg uploaded in the gallery in a php document (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have been brainstorming on how to accomplish this on my blog, which was done in another blog that I worked for a couple of months ago.

When you are redirected to a direct URL of a jpg image on the blog's gallery - for example this screenshot: http://www.gamesteady.com/gallery/half-life-2/half-life-2-screenshots_30.jpg , it automatically inserts the image into the following php document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title> title... </title>
<img src="http://www.gamesteady.com/img/.jpg" border="0" alt=" image" width="100%" style="display:block;" />
<h3>
<a href="http://www.gamesteady.com/pictures/">Back to gallery </a> <span style="font-size: 12px;">or</span> <a href="/img_downloader.php?show_image=.jpg" title="Download picture">Download picture of  image</a>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Even if you enter http://gamesteady.com/gallery/ashdasudh913h.jpg - it launches the same document. Is this accomplished with .htaccess? I have been searching the web a lot for a similar method but couldn't find or understand any.

I will greatly appreciate your assistance on this, as I have been searching a method to do this for a long time. I am still learning php/css and wordpress, but really want this feature for my blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Maybe its from a `RewriteRule` in .htaccess

Comment: Okay I've been playing for hours. I added:
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpg$  /img.php?file=$1.jpg [L,NC,QSA]
to the .htaccess file, and in img.php I created something similar to the one in the post, that I got from the other blog.

It worked, but not exactly. Every image now, displayed on posts/or the blog do not display, and the Stylesheets for the pages on the blog and img.php collide and ruin the pages.

However, if I access, any image directly it worked, and it executed the img.php.

Now I just need to learn how to make img.php display the exact image, that the user tries to execute.

Comment: I feel really dumb now, as I didn't know that php files could not be downloaded, and I though that was the real source of that blog's php file that the RewriteRule redirected it to. I guess I just have to learn some PHP, and accomplish this if its not as simple as I though.